# TLS connection from API Gateway to Ingress

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, kubernetes, traefik-ingress

I am using AWS API Gateway to connect to Kubernetes Ingress via VPC Link. I want to set up TLS connection between API Gateway and Ingress. How can I do this in AWS? All the external connections to API Gateway uses a proper public certificate and SSL termination is happening at API Gateway level. I am trying to avoid sending unencrypted traffic from API Gateway to Ingress. Is it possible to set up a self-signed or ACM based certificate from API Gateway?

Answer (score -1):

Consider using **Ambassador** for that purpose. You can read about it in [this](https://medium.com/faun/how-to-create-an-api-gateway-using-ambassador-on-kubernetes-95f181904ff7) tutorial.

Additional links:

[Enabling HTTPS in Ambassador](https://www.getambassador.io/user-guide/tls-termination/)

[Ambassador on AWS](https://www.getambassador.io/reference/ambassador-with-aws/)